# JSP sessions are returning null values on IOS devises while accessing my website from linux vps server

Tags: ios, linux, jsp, tomcat, vps

I added below lines to my https.conf virtualHost*:80 files in my linux vps server to access session variables.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName example.com
ServerAlias mail.example.com www.example.com
#  DocumentRoot /home/example1/public_html
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
JkMount  /* example
<Proxy *>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
  </Proxy>
  ProxyRequests Off
  ProxyPreserveHost On
  ProxyPass               /       http://localhost:8080/example/
  ProxyPassReverse        /       http://localhost:8080/example/
  ProxyPassReverseCookiePath        /   domine/
</VirtualHost>
```

my website is working fine in all browsers for Windows and Android devices. But java sessions are returning null values on JSP pages when it comes to IOS devises on all browsers.

> testinput.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="testing" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="pdf1">
    <input type="text" name="pdf2">
    <button type="submit">click me</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

> testing.java (servlet)

```
import java.io.IOException; 
import javax.servlet.ServletException; 
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet; 
import javax.servlet.http.Cookie; 
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet; 
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest; 
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse; 
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;


/**  * Servlet implementation class testing  */ @WebServlet("/testing") 

public class testing extends HttpServlet {  
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public testing() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**      
* @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)   
*/  protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {       
// TODO Auto-generated method stub      
response.getWriter().append("Served at: ").append(request.getContextPath());    }


/**      * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)     */     
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {      
String abc = request.getParameter("pdf1").toString();       
String def = request.getParameter("pdf2").toString();

HttpSession sess = request.getSession();        
sess.setAttribute("pdf1", abc);         
sess.setAttribute("pdf2", def);         
if(sess.getAttribute("pdf1")!=null){            
Cookie cook = new Cookie("login", sess.getAttribute("pdf1").toString());             

response.addCookie(cook);       
}       
response.sendRedirect("test.jsp");      
return;     
}
}
```

> test.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    <%try{ %>
    <% Cookie cook[] = request.getCookies();

    for(Cookie c :cook){
        if(c.getName().equals("pdf1")){
            String str = c.getValue();%>
            <p><%=str%></p> 
        <%}
    }%>     
    <p><%=session.getAttribute("pdf1").toString() %></p>
    <p><%=session.getAttribute("pdf2").toString() %></p>
    <%}catch (Exception e){ 
        e.printStackTrace();
        log("erroristhis"+e);
        }%>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: please post code that you use to access the session. And check your configuration: `ProxyPassReverseCookiePath` requires two parameters according to https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html - it might be superfluous. And with http forwarding, you typically want `ProxyPreserveHost On` rather than the default `Off`

Comment: i edited my question and added sample code images. please help me i  am stuck hear

Comment: I just turned on my proxypreservehost on on virtualhost 80 and 443 still they are returning null values on iOS devices.

Comment: Sample code images? Srsly? What's wrong with copying and pasting the code as text into the question?

Comment: i am new to this. this is the first time i am using stackoverflow. i thought images are better. i can add code too.

Comment: Yes please. Code is first and foremost text. Unless you show some glitch in the UI, there's no need for images

Comment: i updated my question please help me fixing this issue. Thank you